# Is it true that if the address of an uninitialized variable is taken, it is initialized to default value?

Tags: c#, pointers, variables, initialization, language-lawyer

I have this code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    unsafe static void f(void* v)
    {}
    static void Main()
    {
        int a;
        unsafe
        {
            f(&a);
        }
        Console.Write(a);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The code has no errors or exceptions. The output of the code is `0`, while `a` is not given any initial values explicitly. Is the code correct and is it true that the compiler initializes `a` to default value implicitly?

Comment: int is a value type which cannot be null so it gets the default value 0.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table for all default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the unsafe code, things may become strange.

First of all, let's look at the [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables) section of the C# language specification.

> A variable must be **definitely assigned** <...> before its value can be obtained.
>
> <...> variables are either **initially assigned** or **initially unassigned**. <...> An initially unassigned variable has no initial value. For an initially unassigned variable to be considered definitely assigned at a certain location, an assignment to the variable must occur in every possible execution path leading to that location.

That is true for the "safe" C# code.

In the unsafe code specification, there is an [address-of operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#the-address-of-operator) description, which tells us:

> The `&` operator does not require its argument to be definitely assigned, but following an `&` operation, the variable to which the operator is applied is considered definitely assigned in the execution path in which the operation occurs. It is the responsibility of the programmer to ensure that correct initialization of the variable actually does take place in this situation.

This is exactly your case. You apply the address-of operator to an *initially unassigned* variable, and after that it is considered by the compiler as a *definitely assigned* variable - so you can use it even in the "safe" context.

The specification tells us that the programmer is responsible for the initialization of the variable. If no initialization occurs, the specification does not guarantee what value will be stored in the actual variable.

The current C# compiler produces such IL code for this:

```
.locals init (
    [0] int32 a
)

IL_0000: ldloca.s 0
IL_0002: conv.u
IL_0003: call void Namespace.Program::f(void*)
```

You see, there is a single local variable of a value type `int32`.
The current CLR (.NET Framework) auto-initializes all local variables with zeroes - that's why the initial value of your variable will be 0 even though it is not initialized in code.

I wouldn't rely on this fact - AFAIK it's not guaranteed and might change in other implementations.